# What is the result of the sum?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, visual, computer-puzzle

$A_1$:

> [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) 0H828JD1FGHODB82JOO
>
> [image: You're Pointless]

$A_2$: [computer-puzzles](/questions/tagged/computer-puzzles) `01111011`

$A_3$: [visual](/questions/tagged/visual)[lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) (Sorry if you are colorblind..)

[image: Add this upside down.]

$A_4$: [visual](/questions/tagged/visual)[computer-puzzles](/questions/tagged/computer-puzzles)

```
    83972748                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & 8
```

$A_5$: [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking)[math](/questions/tagged/math) [image: (!(5%3)^4+7/2)*2]

---

**What is the result of the following calculation?**

> $~~~~~~~A_2 - A_1 + A_3 \times A_4 + A_5$

Comment: In the last equation, I assume you replace each number with the corresponding answer? Also, should it come out to something meaningful?

Comment: @Deusovi I've added some info, but to answer your two questions: yes, replace each number with the number the individual item represents. And no, the answer is a number, but it doesn't have any other meaning that just being the result of the sum.

Comment: I was thinking I am not colorblind but I saw that number _really_ hardly.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear which numbers were numbers and which were variables. Feel fre to roll back if you need to.

Comment: Why do you have to ask questions color blind people cannot answer? Tsk Tsk.

Comment: -1 since this is several questions tenuously linked together - plus, it's not colorblind friendly.

Comment: @Deusovi I'll delete the question. You're indeed right I shouldn't have included the colorblind one.. Also, I think I screwed up on the fifth one myself in terms of math..

Comment: @Kevin: If you want to have multiple puzzles, there should generally be a "satisfying" metapuzzle that combines them all together.

Comment: @Deusovi I'll try to give my next puzzles a bit more thought. I've flagged my own question for deletion.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not sure about this one yet.
2. > This is binary for **123**. (ASCII produces `{`, which is not a number as far as I'm aware.)
3. > I'm colorblind, but the image description is "Add this one upside down". I *think* it's a 9, so the answer would be **6**.
4. > There is a hidden `& 8` after lots of spaces. Taking `&` as bitwise AND, we get **8**.
5. > There is an equation hidden in the source; taking `%` as binary modulus, you get **39**.

Comment: Why are you converting 123 to ascii. I am new to this so want to make sure what am I missing. It dosa not say anywhere to convert

Comment: Also same about the upside down number

Comment: @LearningPhase: It doesn't say to, but numbers between 32 and 128 are ASCII. Binary suggested "computers" to me, so I tried ASCII.

Comment: @LearningPhase: The upside down number comes from the source of the question. Click "edit" on the question (but don't make any changes) and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: For the first I would go for 0 because, well, it's pointless in the formula. The rest is only a red herring (the rest is pointless)

Answer (score 0):

1. > I would go for 0 because it's pointless in the formula. The rest is only a red herring (the rest is also pointless)
2. > This is binary for **123**. (ASCII produces `{`, which is not a number as far as I'm aware.) Thanks to @Deusovi
3. > The image description is "Add this one upside down". Since it's a 9, the answer would be **6**. Thanks to @Deusovi
4. > There is a hidden `& 8` after lots of spaces. Taking `&` as bitwise AND, we get **8**. Thanks to @Deusovi
5. > There is an equation hidden in the source; Also the third image points to a $2px*2px$ GIF. Pluggin them in the equation we get the total result of $[[((5\%3)^4+7/2)*2][2*2]][2*2] = 624$

> So the final result is: $123 - 0 + 6*8 + 624 = 795$
>  I feel something's wrong...